# How do I invoke Ember's component helper programmatically?

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of `foo`s:

```
[
  { name: 'Foo 1' type: 'important' },
  { name: 'Foo 2' type: 'normal' },
  { name: 'Foo 3' type: 'purple' }
]
```

I want to render that list, but some of them have special handling -- not just a class, but entirely different markup.

My first instinct would be to use the [component helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component):

```
{{#each foos as |foo|}}
  {{component (join 'foo-' foo.type) foo=foo}}
{{/each}}
```

The downside to that is that I *must* define a component for each `type` and the server may send me new types that I don't know about. So I'd like to fall back to a basic `foo-generic` component if the `foo-${type}` component isn't defined.

To do that, I figured I'd create a helper:

```
{{#each foos as |foo|}}
  {{foo-entry foo}}
{{/each}}

// app/helpers/foo-entry.js
Ember.Helper.helper(function([ foo ]) {
  // ...
});
```

But I'm left with two questions:

1. how do I get a `container` inside that helper so I can check whether `component:foo-${foo.type}` exists?
2. how do I invoke the `component` helper from within another helper?

Answer (score 4):

I think I can do it with a component instead of a helper:

```
// app/pods/foo-entry/component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: null,

  foo: null,

  componentName: Ember.computed('foo.type', function() {
    const type = this.get('foo.type');

    const exists =
      this.container.lookupFactory(`component:foo-${type}`) != null ||
      this.container.lookupFactory(`template:foo-${type}`) != null;

    return exists ? `foo-${type}` : 'foo-generic';
  })
})

{{!-- app/pods/foo-entry/template.hbs --}}
{{component componentName foo=foo}}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was whipping up, so I would self-accept your answer. :) This is what I've done to solve this in the past and it works well.